# why monocot roots have a wide pith while dicot roots have a narrow pith?

Tags: plant-anatomy

Normally dicot roots have a nartow pith at the center but monocot roots have a wide pith. Is there any specific reason to this?

Comment: Welcome to Biology. Could you add a source or reference?